# Threaded factorial performane in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, factorial

I was searching on stackoverflow for a multi threaded variant of factorial in Java but to my surprise,there wasn't any. So I thought of making it myself because I wanted to see improvement in performance. (I am sharing the code here for anyone who is searching for this.)
Now I want to compare its performance with single threaded iterative approach and recursive approach. But I don't see any performance improvement with it's single threaded counterpart for values as high as 1200! (Long data type cannot hold value of 21! because it is greater than Long.MAX_VALUE.) So how to compare by using a much larger number?I am using BigInteger and 1232! is the maximum value I get by both approaches.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MultiThreadedFactorial
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        long startTime=System.nanoTime();

        int x=1232;

        if(x<2) return;

        int[] array=new int[x-1];//It is x-1 because of 1 is not included in 2...10.
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        {
            array[i]=i+2;
        }

        int[] partA=Arrays.copyOfRange(array,0,array.length/3);//Dividing array into 3 equal parts
        PartialProduct A=new PartialProduct(partA);

        int[] partB=Arrays.copyOfRange(array,array.length/3,2*array.length/3);
        PartialProduct B=new PartialProduct(partB); 

        int[] partC=Arrays.copyOfRange(array,2*array.length/3,array.length);
        PartialProduct C=new PartialProduct(partC);

        A.start();
        B.start();
        C.start();

        A.join();
        B.join();
        C.join();

        BigInteger bi=new BigInteger(A.product+"");
        bi=bi.multiply(new BigInteger(B.product+""));
        bi=bi.multiply(new BigInteger(C.product+""));

        System.out.println(bi.toString());

        long endTime=System.nanoTime();
        float totalTime=(endTime-startTime)/1000000000f;
        System.out.println("Took "+totalTime+" seconds!");
    }

    static long multiply(long... numbers)
    {
        long factorial=1;
        for(long n:numbers)
            factorial*=n;
        return factorial;
    }

}

class PartialProduct extends Thread
{
    int[] numbers;
    BigInteger product=new BigInteger("1");

    public PartialProduct(int[] numbers)
    {
        this.numbers=numbers;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        for(int n:numbers)
            product=product.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(n));
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/FastFactorialFunctions.htm for competetive single threaded algorithms.

Comment: I wonder why the question is getting down votes

Comment: I guess because you're not really asking a question. If you have found a solution to a problem, and want to share this, the proper way to do it is to post a question, and then answer your own question.

Comment: Nice. I'll convert it to self answered style

Answer (score 1):

It's a whole lot easier to write parallel versions of factorial with Java stream API available in Java 8.

A single threaded implementation might look like this:

```
  static BigInteger sequentialFactorial(int n)
  {
    if (n < 2)
      return BigInteger.ONE;
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(2, n)
        .sequential()
        .mapToObj(BigInteger::valueOf)
        .reduce(BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger::multiply, BigInteger::multiply);
  }
```

A parallel/multi-threaded version is a trivial change:

```
  static BigInteger parallelFactorial(int n)
  {
    if (n < 2)
      return BigInteger.ONE;
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(2, n)
        .parallel()
        .mapToObj(BigInteger::valueOf)
        .reduce(BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger::multiply, BigInteger::multiply);
  }
```

If you time these in a sensible way (for example, 1000 iterations each calculating 1000!), you should see significant speedups on a multi-core machine.